# Call function with parameter given in arguments lists

Tags: java

I want to receive a function in parameter and call it with one parameter as:

```
public static <T> T foo(Callable<T> func)
{
     return func.call("bar");
}
```

But it call doesn't take any parameter. Any idea on how can I do this?

No matter how much I search, I dont find anything that help me...

Comment: I don't understand. You want to call a function that doesn't take any argument, with an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Callable<T>` only has one method: `T call()`.

If you want something different, you will need to use a different parameter type, for example:

```
public interface CallableWithString<T> {
    T call(String arg); //Assuming you want a string argument
}
```

Then your function can do:

```
public static <T> T foo(CallableWithString<T> func) {
    return func.call("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `call` method defined in `Callable` has no parameters defined so you cannot pass anything to it.

Depending on what you want to do exactly you can write your own interface for that:

```
public interface CallableWithParameters<T> {
  public T call(Object... arguments);
}
```

Then you call it in different ways:

```
call();
call(someObject);
call("someString", 42);
```